# Server not showing the right file on webpage

Tags: wordpress, apache, server, gravity-forms-plugin

I am testing/learning how to send info from a Gravity form to a test file on my website.
I am using a testfile.txt that I added in var/www/ which is the location of the Wordpress directory.

The command I am running updates that file and I am able to see its contents when i go to the domain: mywebsite.com/testfile.txt.

The first time I run the Gravity form, I can see the changes on the webpage. However, after updating its contents to something else, the webpage does not update despite reloading it.

To troubleshoot this, I SSH'd into the server to see if the file was being updated and indeed it was...

So, basically, the file is being updated on the server but not on my GoDaddy domain... Has anybody encountered a problem like this? And if so does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am no Expert in this field, Beginner to be honest. When I was learning Python flask a framework for building website, I had similar issue. Maybe the problem is that, when you visit your website it loads from the cache. To solve that press 'ctrl + F5', it forces a cache refresh, and will guarantee that IF the content is changed, you will get the new content. Again, I am beginner myself.

Comment: I wish it was this simple... We tried doing on different browsers and computers and tried the hard reset of the webpage both through commands and manually and still nothing... It just seems like GoDaddy is pulling the file from some unknown place... I searched for testfile.txt in the whole server through ssh and there were 4 instances. All four of those instances have the results I want, but the website doesn't... Extremely weird.

Comment: I guess that's a problem I can't help with, sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

As @Sadman said, whenever I don't see my content getting updated I do a hard refresh or delete the cookies and cache manually. Either one of these solved my problem. To make a hard refresh press ctrl+shift+r or ctrl+f5 or shift+f5 on windows. On MAC this is cmd+R. I hope this helps!